# How compress android bitmap and don't change width or high

Tags: android, android-bitmap, image-compression

I want to compress bitmap , but I don't want to change the width and heigh.
My bitmap type is .PNG, So  `bitmap.compress()` does not have any effect. I need a method to resolve it.

Comment: check this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966

Comment: I can't change image width and height , they are important to me,I have to compress the picture without changing the width and height @SadiqMdAsif

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);` method change the bitmap width and height.@dipali

Comment: It's not possible. The quality parameter of the Bitmap.compress function is ignored in the case of PNG, it's already as small as possible. Realistically, if you could losslessly compress a PNG to a smaller file size without changing the width or height, don't you think it would already do that by default? In some image editing software e.g. GIMP you can adjust the compression level of a PNG to get a smaller size at the expense of slower encoding/decoding, but to do that on Android you would need a PNG library.

Comment: Thank you,I know my problem is almost impossible to reslove by my way, I only want to try to find the answer. I try to `opt.inSampleSize = 2;Bitmap result = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(isBm, null, opt);` and then `matrixs.setScale(2f, 2f); Bitmap result2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(result, 0, 0, result.getWidth(), result.getHeight(), matrixs, true);`The bitmap width not change and the size has been compressed, but scaled back@samgak

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reduce image size or bitmap bytes count, here is good library on GitHub:

https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor